# Mongoose Aggregate match if an Array contains any value of another Array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, match

I am trying to match by comparing the values inside the values of another array, and return it if any one of the values in the 1st array match any one value of the 2nd array. I have a user profile like this

```
{
"user": "bob"
"hobbies": [jogging]
 },
{
"user": "bill"
"hobbies": [reading, drawing]
 },
{
"user": "thomas"
"hobbies": [reading, cooking]
 }
{
"user": "susan"
"hobbies": [coding, piano]
 }
```

My mongoose search query as an example is this array [coding, reading] (but could include any hobby value) and i would like to have this as an output:

```
 {
"user": "bill"
"hobbies": [reading, drawing]
 },
{
"user": "thomas"
"hobbies": [reading, cooking]
 }
{
"user": "susan"
"hobbies": [coding, piano]
 }
```

I tried:

```
{"$match": {"$expr": {"$in": [searchArray.toString(), "$hobbies"]}}}
```

but this only works aslong as the search array has only one value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const searchArray = ["reading", "coding"];

const orArray = searchArray.map((seachValue) => {
  return {
    hobies: searchValue,
  }
});

collection.aggregate([{
  $match: { $or: orArray }
}])
```

The query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$or": [
        {
          hobbies: "reading"
        },
        {
          hobbies: "coding"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Or you can use another way, no need to handle arr:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      hobbies: {
        $in: [
          "reading",
          "coding"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Run here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_NxTO4P1HN5)

Comment: But this would only work if the searchArray is the same everytime, i forgot to mention that the searchArray could be any hobby value

Comment: You can handle it in NodeJS, use forEach or map to build array for $or conditions. And pass it to the query. I will update description

Comment: I added another way, check it

Comment: Awesome thank you! the orArray approach was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: I also added another way. I prefer the 2nd way, it's cleaner, lighter way. If your searchArray is array of string, you can pass it to $in immediate